# UIPickerViews not showing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipickerview, xib

I have two `UIPickerView`'s which have different contents though when I run the app they are not showing which is really weird as they are definitely on the xib file, I also have a date-picker in the same file which does show which is really weird.

I was wondering if this happened a lot and if there was a way around it.

I have already tried cleaning the app, deleting and then reinputing the pickers.

Please say of you want any more information about the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: r u sure ur xib is connected....

Comment: one hundred percent as if I change things then run it then it makes the changes

Comment: make sure delegate is connected to file-owner...

Comment: Ahh that was it thanks so much it had me stumped cause I didn't think it was that simple

Comment: @Bhrigesh post your comment as an answer if you want rep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure delegate is connected to file-owner...

Answer (score 2):

You must take us some code, how you show them.
Try to create your UIPickerView's in code for examplу, in class when you showing pickers  (in header) add `<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>`, in .m file of this class implementing this protocols' methods and create pickers:

```
UIPickerView *myPickerViewOne = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 160, 200)];
myPickerViewOne.delegate = self;
myPickerViewOne.dataSourse = self;
myPickerViewOne.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

UIPickerView *myPickerViewTwo = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 200, 160, 200)];
myPickerViewTwo.delegate = self;  //or other
myPickerViewTwo.dataSourse = self;  //or other
myPickerViewTwo.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[self.view addSubview:myPickerViewTwo];
```

Comment: Though if by the end of the day he has not answered will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Check that the UIPickerView's delegate is connected to file-owner:

```
picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self;
```